# What sleep command in Ubuntu do Hardwarewize?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sleep

Say I have a very simple script that does the

```
sleep 0.001
```

command in Ubuntu.
I want to know if this command effect the c state of the core or the package somehow. Does it force a c state on the hardware?
Thanks!

Code example:

```
/bin/sh
sleep 0.01
sleep 0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

The sleep is purely software, the process executing it is not eligible for the CPU/cores during at least the specified time, but all your Ubuntu is not frozen and the CPU/cores are available for other processes. After if there is nothing to do during the sleep perhaps the CPU/cores save energy, but this is not directly required by the command sleep itself